# gas not honoring short jump suffix .d8

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, gnu-assembler

I want to force gas to emit a relative conditional jump in a short opcode, but it always uses rel32 encoding. Here is my code:

```
.text
.org 0x123450
.globl test
test:
je.d8 0x123450
```

Which emits, when compiled:

```
$ as x.S -o x && objdump -d x
0000000000123450 <test>:
  123450:   0f 84 00 00 00 00       je     123456 <test+0x6>
```

When I use the label, i.e.

```
je test
```

it correctly produces

```
  123450:   74 fe                   je     123450 <test>
```

How do I force the latter while still being able to numerically enter the address?

Comment: Note that `.org` is relative to section start and will pad your code. The linker will still choose section bases so if you use an absolute address the assembler does not know if it will be in range after linking hence the rel32. That said, you should be able to force a short jump.

Comment: If all else fails, you can inline the bytecode like so: `.byte 0x74, 0xFE`. (If you do this it's highly recommended to comment what the instruction actually is. I don't have the opcodes memorized, and it's unreasonable to expect other people maintaining your code to do the same.)